# Why do we need to start session and what is session basically?

Tags: php

why do I need to start session and what is session and where to start session 
Help would be highly appreciated 
best of luck

Comment: You should google it..

Answer (score 0):

"Sessions are a simple way to store data for individual users against a unique session ID. This can be used to persist state information between page requests. Session IDs are normally sent to the browser via session cookies and the ID is used to retrieve existing session data. The absence of an ID or session cookie lets PHP know to create a new session, and generate a new session ID."
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: thank u bro for ur help u know im new in PHP can u plz tell me simple way